# Not getting split value in dynamic soql query

Tags: apex, dynamic-soql

Please help me how to get value for split values "valueArray[1]" in below query.

I am trying to fetch the records, but i found issue in writing dynamic query.
Please let me know if I am missing syntax in belowsoql query.

```
List<String> valueArray = new List<String>();
    for(String strValues : listOfValues) {
     valueArray = strValues.split('-');
     Integer intValue = Integer.ValueOf(valueArray[1]);
    
    for(sObject sObj : Database.query('SELECT Id FROM ' + valueArray[0] + ' WHERE CreatedDate < Last_N_Days:intValue ')) {
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! `valueArray` is a String in this example, you cannot access the index of a String. What does `listOfValues` look like, something like {'Account-20', 'Contact-10'}` i.e look for Accounts created in last 20 days, look for Contacts created in last 10 days?

Answer (score 1):

Bind variables in Dynamic Apex do not support complex expressions (e.g. accessing an array), so you just need to use normal string concatenation:

```
for(sObject sObj : Database.query('SELECT Id FROM ' + 
    String.escapeSingleQuote(valueArray[0]) + 
    ' WHERE CreatedDate < Last_N_Days:' +
    String.escapeSingleQuote(valueArray[1]))) {
```

Comment: SOQL injection attack prevention encoding should be added here...

Comment: @PhilW Fair enough. I try not to assume too much about where the input comes from, but as a general best practice, one should definitely escape quotes.

Comment: in valueArray, there are multiple objects and it's related number but I am getting only one sobject from valueArray[0], after that execution is being stopped. I have checked in debug logs.

Comment: @sfdcfox if the OP is looking to query many objects (unknown from List), how would we tackle or improve [this](https://codeshare.io/eVm3bx) from platform limit perspective?

Comment: @TSmith I don't want to assume too much, the query looks like it's incorrect anyways (they probably meant `=` instead of `<`). If that's true, Database.getUpdated returns records created and updated within a time window, for free (no governor limits are used aside from CPU/heap). If they need to query hundreds of objects, then context will matter. Might need to call it from a loop client-side, or batchable, etc. It's too vague to give a specific solution.